Wavy underlines almost look like strikethroughs in VSCode
I don't know why underlines for warnings/errors in my VSCode collide with texts like this.
I want to keep the lines, but right now they look annoying. Does anyone know how to reposition them?
VSCode version: 1.88.0
OS: macOS Sonoma 14.4.1

Try playing with some display scaling setting on your Mac - I wonder if something is off with them and its confusing VS Code somehow.  Weird things like this I've seen happen because of scaling issues, not only in VS Code but other applications (mostly on windows though)

@TimothyG. Thank you for your comment. I've tried playing with my display scaling like you said, but nothing changes. So I dug a little deeper in my settings.json, and found out editorError.border and editorWarning.border in workbench.colorCustomizations were the problems. I accidentally set the borders and background color to be similar, still don't know why the lines moved up though.

If you haven't modified your font setting, I'd suggest raising an issue ticket to at least make maintainers aware of this. if you do, please add a link here to your issue ticket.
